# What is the meaning of the phrase "outside of opens/clicks"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Kindly explain the meaning of the second sentence. I am confused with phrases "email measurement" and "outside of opens/clicks".

From our own data we’ve seen a sharp rise in the use of hashtags. This is no longer just a fad – subscribers use the hashtag to search for the promotion in social media instead.This has profound implications for email measurement, as a substantial percentage of responses are being generated outside of opens/clicks as a result.
https://econsultancy.com/blog/67297-what-were-the-key-email-marketing-trends-from-2015

Comment: *Open* and *click* are terminology specific to email marketing analytics, referring to possible actions taken by the recipient of a marketing email. I suggest you brush up on [email marketing terminology](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/7595/The-Ultimate-Glossary-44-Email-Marketing-Terms-Marketers-Must-Know.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I gather from this: conventional email marketing is: you send emails and you measure, with some technical tricks, the numbers of emails that are opened and the number of times that people click on links in the emails.

The new stuff is emails that have a hashtag as a subject, e.g. #NewAndCool. People no longer open the mail, but start looking for the hashtag themselves on various social media. So you might think that your email marketing campaign is not so effective anymore, because you get less opens and clicks than before, while in fact people look for information in a different way, using the hashtag that you used in the mail subject.